# How to count elements from list if specific key present in list using scala?

Tags: list, scala

I have following list structure -

```
"disks" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "A",
        "memberNo" :1 
    }, 
{
        "name" : "B",
        "memberNo" :2 
    },
{
        "name" : "C",
        "memberNo" :3 
    },
{
        "name" : "D",

    }
]
```

I have many elements in list and want to check for 'memberNo', if it exists
I want count of from list elements.

e.g. here count will be 3

How do I check if key exists and get count of elements from list using scala??

Answer (score 4):

First create class to represent your input data

```
case class Disk (name : String, memberNo : String)
```

Next load data from repository (or other datasource)

```
val disks: List[Disk] = ...
```

And finally count

```
disks.count(d => Option(d.memberNo).isDefined)
```

Comment: Note that case classes are fantastic to represent json data models, especially when integrated with Jackson. Take a look at a similar question where I gave a code sample that uses Jackson: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26494306/1028765

Answer (score 2):

In a similar fashion as in @SergeyLagutin answer, consider this case class

```
case class Disk (name: String, memberNo: Option[Int] = None)
```

where missing `memberNo` are defaulted with `None`; and this list,

```
val disks = List( Disk("A", Some(1)), 
                  Disk("B", Some(2)),
                  Disk("C", Some(3)),
                  Disk("D"))
```

Then with `flatMap` we can filter out those disks with *some* `memberNo`, as follows,

```
disks.flatMap(_.memberNo)
res: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Namely, for the counting,

```
disks.flatMap(_.memberNo).size
res: Int = 3
```

Likewise, with a for comprehension,

```
for (d <- disks ; m <- d.memberNo) yield m
res: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```